# assume IAM roles using user name and password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

It seems really insecure to store permanent IAM access credentials (key, secret) on the instance or any other place.

The way I understood roles - it would make sense if I could manage permissions to perform certain tasks using roles:

- setup the role,setup user group with permission to assume that role, add users to that group
- from command line type something like "ec2_assume_role rolename time_till_expiration"
- then at the prompt enter my username and pwd
- get those temporary keys (could script to set them directly into the env)

From what I found in IAM documentation - assuming role requires a set of keys - so is not really meant for a human. I could setup a server that enables something similar to the above but that server would have to have its own key stored or at least in memory, plus I would have to duplicate username / pwd management that IAM already does pretty well.

Am I missing/misunderstanding something ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a [Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566).

> The token vending machine (TVM) is a server-based reference
>   application that serves temporary credentials to remote clients to
>   sign web requests to Amazon Web Services (AWS). The TVM is
>   particularly useful for mobile client devices that use temporary
>   credentials to access AWS. Both the AWS SDK for Android and the AWS
>   SDK for iOS provide a sample client, which your mobile application can
>   use to access the TVM and receive security tokens.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds about right.

Still, why doesn't IAM itself do this kind of thing?

Also (big difference) this TVM app would require separate user management - users/passwords etc , which IAM already does quite adequately.